# Why Statefull widget's build() function is called before initState()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a wrapper to call init() with stateless widgets:

```
class StatefulWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulWrapper({this.child, this.init});
  final Widget child;
  final void Function() init;
  @override
  _StatefulWrapperState createState() => _StatefulWrapperState();
}

class _StatefulWrapperState extends State<StatefulWrapper> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.init != null) widget.init();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child ?? SizedBox();
}
```

And here's a simple example of using it:

```
class SomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulWrapper(
      init: () => print('---------- step 1'),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: generateWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget generateWidget() {
  print('---------- step 2');
  return Container(width: 50, height: 50);
}
```

Output:

```
I/flutter ( 2810): ---------- step 2
I/flutter ( 2810): ---------- step 1
```

**Why step2 is printed before step1?**

Flutter 1.22.2 stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken. Your *own* build function does **not** get called before initState.

But your widget takes a fully built child and an init function.

That requires that the *child* is built *first* to get passed as a parameter.

That is what you see.